# All import is not working

Tags: android, import

Computer is turned off on the job.
and restart my computer.

than, android studio was broken.

All import is not working.

Install and was able to practice again. But did the same.

Error message is as follows : unuesd import statement.

what shoud i do?

Comment: Seriously - how would anyone be able to help you on the base of the information you provided?

Comment: But it was all....
Electric temporarily off. and restart android studio 
But, android studio was not working....

Comment: if you are using eclipse it is an big issue. R.java doesn't save stuff if eclipse is abruptly ends the task, because of which you don't get any imports from R. try cleaning your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the imports with grey lines and try to run.

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
->
import android.support.v7.app.;

How do you use? ActionBarActivity

"import android.support.v7.appActionBarActivity;" is under gray line

"import android.support.v7;" is working

Comment: sorry coment is mistake.
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

All import is gray under line

Comment: All files and custom options delete. I re-install android stuoid. So i need a time. thanks  continuously answer.

Comment: @Audi - you're going a long way for a reputation bump... ;)

Comment: I don't know the reason, but act. Thank you.

Comment: @jangroth I just joined so yeah! xP